# Getting dired to open an xterm instance without waiting

Tags: dired, shell-command

I like to use `dired-do-shell-command` to open audio and video files in an independent terminal using the default command

```
gnome-terminal -- mplayer *
```

and this works great. But now I've changed my window manager to Stumpwm and starting up a Gnome app when none are running takes forever. However, when I use a command like

```
xterm -e "mplayer * "
```

to do the same thing, Emacs is waiting for `xterm` to finish and stuck until then. So how do I open an independent instance (I've tried giving `xterm` a new title with `xterm -T` and I've tried using a `xterm -e /bin/bash -l -c` as suggested
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373377/start-xterm-with-different-shell-and-execute-commands), but neither works). So how do I start an independent instance of `xterm`?

I realize this is a borderline question for the Unix Stack exchange but I thought I'd post it here since it might depend on the specifics of Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287350/start-a-new-process-without-blocking-the-terminal): one just has to add a & at the end of the command!